# Mysqld Service Suddenly Down, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, mysql

My mysqld service just crashed and I have no idea how to fix it.

I checked for syslog and this is what I got

```
May 23 00:15:38 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:15:38 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 23 00:15:38 www mysqld:
May 23 00:15:38 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:15:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
May 23 00:15:39 www mysqld: Warning: Memory not freed: 520
May 23 00:15:39 www mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/www.example.com.pid ended
May 23 00:17:30 www mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
May 23 00:17:30 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:17:30 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.23-MariaDB-1:10.3.23+maria~xenial) starting as process 5554 ...
May 23 00:17:30 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:17:30 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.23 started; log sequence number 795310001; transaction id 728172
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld:
May 23 00:18:03 www mysqld: Warning: Memory not freed: 520
May 23 00:18:03 www mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/www.example.com.pid ended
```

Its my first time to encounter this problem ?
How to fix this issue ?

I really appreciate it. I am very new to sysadmin. Thanks a lot :)